# Blank ASP.NET Core 2.0 app fails on Azure with 502.5 error, failed to bind, EACCESS permission denied

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app, and deployed it to an app service on Azure. However, no matter what, it always results in an IIS 502.5 error when trying to access it from Azure. It works fine locally.

**Repro steps**

1. Create a new repository
2. Clone repository in Visual Studio
3. Create a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app in VS within the new repository
4. Push your changes to the repository
5. In Azure, create a new app service
6. Link up Continuous Deployment to the repository, selecting ASP.NET Core as the app type
7. When done building, try accessing the website

Notice it just goes to an HTTP 502.5 error page.

Attempting to run the site from command line in Kudo results in the following...

Any ideas? Been trying to figure this out for the past two days! ASP.NET Core 2.0 websites were previously working on my Azure, but then just mysteriously stopped working for me.

```
dotnet doesthiswork.dll
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]

      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv4 loopback interface: 'Error -4092 EACCES permission denied'.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]

      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Error -4092 EACCES permission denied'.

crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]

      Unable to start Kestrel.

System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -4092 EACCES permission denied) (Error -4092 EACCES permission denied) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4092 EACCES permission denied

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.LibuvFunctions.ThrowError(Int32 statusCode)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.LibuvFunctions.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(IPEndPoint endPoint)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.ListenTcp(Boolean useFileHandle)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.CreateListenSocket()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Listener listener)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.CallbackAdapter`1.<>c.<.cctor>b__3_1(Object callback, Object state)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.LibuvThread.DoPostWork()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.LibuvTransport.<BindAsync>d__20.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.LibuvTransport.<BindAsync>d__20.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindEndpointAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindLocalhostAsync>d__6.MoveNext()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindLocalhostAsync>d__6.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<StartAsync>d__23`1.MoveNext()
```

The app error analytics page says the following

```
Your app failed to make an outbound TCP connection because the machine-wide TCP Connection limit was hit
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had another app service that was going rogue and consuming all the TCP and socket connections, and therefore any other app services couldn't connect.

Once I stopped that rogue app service, things started working again.